# Check if inputted value is associated with another in its row from a database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, authentication

I have a problem that I am not sure where to start with. Basically I have a login page and because there will be multiple users logging in, I thought that I might use my database to validate their logins:

A. Check if their usernames are in my (pre-created) database.

B. Check if the inputted username and inputted password match to the same person (in the same row.)

I am aware this is definitely not the safest way to do this, but it is for a school project, so who cares :)

I am using JS, jQuery, SQL and as little PHP as possible.
To connect and manipulate my database I am using the syntax that goes along with:
Not sure what this is called, whether it is a language, or just part of JS.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
 etc. 
}
```

where `db` is opening the conn. to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

Using the WHERE operator combined with the AND operator to select multiple. End code looks like this:

```
    let uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
    let pword = document.getElementById("password").value;
    db.transaction(function(lx) {
        lx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?)', [uname, pword]);
//Runs code if above statement returns true
            
    });
```

My next question is how I would output this? How do i tell the user yay or nay?